# Mongo Comparison Operations

Tags: mongodb

I have a sample collection like the following.

> db.sample.find();

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c804b9db13da086828b414"), "name" : "h", "ids" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], "department" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c804b9db13da086828b415"), "name" : "n", "ids" : [ 3, 4, 5 ], "department" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c804b9db13da086828b416"), "name" : "m", "ids" : [ 4, 5, 6 ], "department" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c804b9db13da086828b417"), "name" : "h", "ids" : [ 1, 3, 4 ], "department" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c808d2db13da086828b418"), "name" : "t", "fullname" : "t", "ids" : [ 5, 6, 7 ] }
```

When I query

> db.sample.find({ids:{$lt:4,$gt:3}});

I expected it would return no documents as there no documents with value <4 and >3 as one of the ids' values.

But it returned 2 documents.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c804b9db13da086828b415"), "name" : "n", "ids" : [ 3, 4, 5 ], "department" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c804b9db13da086828b417"), "name" : "h", "ids" : [ 1, 3, 4 ], "department" : "B" }
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a field contains an array and query has multiple conditional operators, the field as a whole will match if either a single array element meets the conditions or a combination of array elements meet the conditions.

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-a-field-that-contains-an-array) you will find more description

Use of $elemMatch make strict comparisons for array only. So you can use query like:

```
db.collection.find({ ids: { $elemMatch:{ $lt:4, $gt:3  } } })
```

Answer (score 1):

The way it works is that one element satisfies the first condition and another element satisfies the second condition (of course one element could satisfy both  conditions), as long as all the conditions are satisfied this way the document will be returned.

Specifically:

`[3, 4, 5]` is found because the element 3 is less than 4 and element 4 and 5 are greater than 3 - so both of your conditions are satisfied from those two element

`[1, 3, 4]` is found because element 1 and 3 are less than 4 and element 4 is greater than 3

see https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/query-documents/#arrays in the section named "Combination of Elements Satisfies the Criteria"

Now if you want to find documents **that at least one element satisfy all** such conditions you should use `$elemMatch`.

In your example that would be:

```
db.sample.find( { ids: { $elemMatch: { $lt: 4, $gt: 3 } } } )
```